# C Code How to add sounds to .exe using resource folder?

Tags: c, windows, audio, resources, codeblocks

I am using windows, codeblocks. I have managed to include an icon for the exectable using a .rc file and including it there using this line of code:

```
MAINICON ICON "trees_XZ1_icon.ico"
```

How to do in the same manner with a .wav file (sound)?

Comment: If you're referring to [Windows Resource Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio?view=vs-2017), they definitely can contain arbitrary binary data, though your particular editor may not support it.

Comment: I am referring to .rc files. in c++ , there is a option "WAV" which includes sounds into the resource, but I cant find its equivalent in c

Comment: This is how resources were added to executables in the Windows 3.0 era, but now it's generally the case you either have resource bundles (e.g. a .zip file) or just plain `.wav` files on disk. If you need it self-contained, you may need to hack around a fair bit, especially if trying to include MP3 instead of WAV.

Comment: Try `ID_SOUND WAVE "SoundFile.wav"`. Accepted files **must be** in wave format.